# Python logging + webassets + cssutils: set log level for cssutils

Tags: python, css, logging

I am using jinja and webassets for my assets management along with cssutils to minify and combine css files. the problem is when cssutils produces a "fatal error" it kicks off the email alert system I have set up with python logging. The thing is the errors are not really fatal the parser doesnt know the property but the page still renders fine and the css is valid css ( its mostly from twitter bootstrap  that it is companing about ). how can I set cssutils to surpress its errors into a lower level so I dont get 50 error alerts because it doesnt like gradient syntax.

```
[ERROR 2012-04-23 13:59:35,844] - MainProcess (13706) - (errorhandler:__handle:100) Property: Invalid value for "CSS Level 2.1" property: rgba(0,0,0,.75) [3518:3: background]
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the level of the handler to be higher than the level you want to suppress, or add a `logging.Filter` to the relevant handler and set its level to be higher than the level you want to suppress.